# How to show preview selected options of multiselect attribute in magento2 product form?

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, knockoutjs

I am trying to extend the Magento multiselect element to show the preview of options selected as per below screenshot.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/uUYtR.png
[image]

I tried to override Template file and js file as below

```
<div class="selected-options" data-bind="text: selectedOptionsLabels"></div>
<select multiple class="admin__control-multiselect" data-bind="
    attr: {
        name: inputName,
        id: uid,
        size: size ? size : '6',
        disabled: disabled,
        'aria-describedby': noticeId,
        placeholder: placeholder
    },
    hasFocus: focused,
    optgroup: options,
    selectedOptions: value,
    optionsValue: 'value',
    optionsText: 'label'"
></select>
```

Js file

```
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/**
 * @api
 */
define([
    'underscore',
    'mageUtils',
    'Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select',
    'ko',
    'jquery'
], function (_, utils, Select, ko) {
    'use strict';

    return Select.extend({
        defaults: {
            size: 5,
            elementTmpl: 'My_CustomModule/form/element/multiselect',
            listens: {
                value: 'setDifferedFromDefault selectedOptionsLabels setPrepareToSendData'
            },
            selectedOptionsLabels: "",
        },
        initObservable: function () {
            this._super();
            this.observe(this.selectedOptionsLabels);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        setInitialValue: function () {
            this._super();
            this.initialValue = utils.copy(this.initialValue);
            this.indexedOptions = utils.copy(this.indexedOptions);
            this._super()
                .observe('selectedOptionsLabels');
            return this;
        },

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        normalizeData: function (value) {
            if (utils.isEmpty(value)) {
                value = [];
            }

            return _.isString(value) ? value.split(',') : value;
        },

        /**
         * Sets the prepared data to dataSource
         * by path, where key is component link to dataSource with
         * suffix "-prepared-for-send"
         *
         * @param {Array} data - current component value
         */
        setPrepareToSendData: function (data) {
            if (_.isUndefined(data) || !data.length) {
                data = '';
            }
            this.updateLabels(data);

            this.source.set(this.dataScope + '-prepared-for-send', data);
        },

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        getInitialValue: function () {
            var values = [
                    this.normalizeData(this.source.get(this.dataScope)),
                    this.normalizeData(this.default)
                ],
                value;

            values.some(function (v) {
                return _.isArray(v) && (value = utils.copy(v)) && !_.isEmpty(v);
            });

            return value;
        },

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        hasChanged: function () {
            var value = this.value(),
                initial = this.initialValue;
            return !utils.equalArrays(value, initial);
        },
        updateLabels: function (value) {
            var selectedLabels = [];
            let d = this.indexedOptions;
            let i = 0;
            while (i < value.length) {
                let option = d[value[i]];
                selectedLabels.push(option ? option.label : '');
                i++;
            }
            console.log("updatelatehas change:" + selectedLabels);
            this.selectedOptionsLabels = selectedLabels;

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        reset: function () {
            this.value(utils.copy(this.initialValue));
            this.error(false);

            return this;
        },

        /**
         * @inheritdoc
         */
        clear: function () {
            this.value([]);
            this.error(false);

            return this;
        }
    });
});
```

pls help on this topic

Comment: Are you able to do it?

Comment: Yes i able to do it